# How do I 'CreateFileInfos' on a Media Svc Asset from Python?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-media-services

I'm a .NET dev, but I've been attempting to use the Python azure-mgmt-media/storage packages and have finally been able to:

```
1) create a media asset
2) upload the files into the media assets storage container
```

but the media asset didn't "own" the files (ie they weren't listed as part of the media asset).  After hours of googling I found a REST call that creates a stub which is:    {{RESTAPIEndpoint}}/CreateFileInfos?assetid='nb:cid:UUID:{myAssetId}'.  This seems so strange - it's just a /GET but it's creating something attached to my asset telling it to accept files I guess.

I'd really prefer to do this part with Python as well, but I can't find a method in the azure-mgmt-media package.  Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the Assets? If you can use our v3 APis, which are currently in preview (and do not support all of the encoding features yet), you can process content in Azure by using a SAS URL. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/job-input-from-http-how-to for documentation, as well as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-tutorial-with-api

Comment: Hi @AnilMurching, I don't need any encoding.  I just need to create the media asset and push up an mp4 file associated with it.  Are you saying I should use straight REST?  I've been struggling with azure-mgmt-media but I can't find a way to add the association between the media asset and the files pushed into its storage container.  I don't really understand why it doesn't just "see" the files, but with the REST api there's a CreateFileInfos step that creates the required link.  The tutorial I followed did use the SAS URL to handle the upload but still required the extra step.

Comment: latest v3 API does not rely on Asset Files. We got rid of that because it caused this kind of confusion for customers.  I would suggest looking at the samples that Anil pointed to for v3, and work with the latest Python package for the v3 APi where there is no requirement to use Asset Files any longer.

Comment: @johndeu, I have azure-mgmt-media v1.0.0rc1 and I think that uses V3. After I create the asset and use blob storage to upload the files to the asset's storage container they aren't 'connected' less I call CreateFileInfo.    Problem is the Python stuff has no examples and little documentation - I bet there's a way to upload the file using the UploadURL and maybe that would connect them, but I can't find any method for that.  Doesn't seem like python is really supported - I should probably just stick with REST, but the python api cuts down the amount of code needed.

Comment: Correct, azure-mgmt-media v1.0.0rc1 uses our v3 APIs. As John said, in v3, we don't require/return any AssetFiles (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/master/specification/mediaservices/resource-manager/Microsoft.Media/preview/2018-06-01-preview/examples/assets-get-by-name.json). Your Asset should have been created once the MP4 upload is complete. What would you want to do next? (Also note: the Azure Portal is still on v2 APIs, and will not recognize v3 entities correctly)

Comment: @AnilMurching, yes the media asset shows up but the type is (empty) even after I use the azure-storage-blob package to upload my file.  Only after I execute the CreateFileInfos does my container show a type (and shows the file attached to the media asset).  Maybe this is just a bug.  Thankfully, time is not a factor in this batch process so I can execute the extra steps of getting the REST access_token and the CreateFileInfos call.   If you guys have any python examples I would love to see them - maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: ... "does my container show a type (and shows the file attached to the media asset)." - how are you checking this? Using APIs, or Azure Portal or some other tool? Can you please share the data center name, and examples of Asset names/IDs for one without CreateFileInfo, and a different Asset where you have called CreateFileInfo? Thanks